# Beautifulsoup4 wont parse the text if it's in a loop buit it will outside of one, why is that?

Tags: python, django, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im currently using beautifulsoup4 and html5lib. In my views when I loop through the contents like this

```
def get_vlad(url):
            html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
            divs = soup.findAll('section', 'videos')

            entries = [{'text': div.strong.a.text,
                        'link': div.a.get('href'),
                        'img': div.find('img').get('src')
                        } for div in divs]
            return entries

        trap_free = get_vlad(vlad_url)
```

and in my context

```
        context = {
        "entries": entries,
        "url": url,
        "vlad_url": vlad_url,
        "free": trap_free
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

and in my template

```
        {% for f in free %}
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="margin-top: 30px">
          <a href="{{vlad_url}}{{f.link}}">press</a>
          <img src="{{f.img}}" alt="{{ f.text }}" class="img-responsive post">
          <p>text: {{f.text}}</p>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

the text does not show. But if I don't use a loop like in the following example

```
 html = requests.get(vlad_url, headers=headers)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
 divs = soup.find('section', 'videos')

 img = divs.find('img').get('src')
 text = divs.strong.a.text
 link = divs.a.get('href')


diction = [{
     'img': img,
     'text': text,
     'link': link
 }]

   context = {
    ...
     "lad": diction,
   }
```

and in my views

```
{% for d in lad %}
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="margin-top: 30px">
      <a href="{{vlad_url}}{{d.link}}">press</a><br>
      <img src="{{d.img}}" alt="{{ d.text }}" class="img-responsive post">
      <p>text: {{d.text}}</p>
  </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Everything is returned including text. It works fine. What's going on? What's the proper syntax since mine isn't workin? I've also tried

```
'text': div.strong.a.contents[0]
```

and

```
'text': div.strong.a.string,
```

and just to be complete the following is the html im scraping, in case it helps

```
<section class="videos">
   <section class="box">
        <a href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhaw8XS8ZJuKleo90r" class="video-box">
            <img src="http://hw-static.example.org/u/pic/2016/05/gbllWKHPGcQy.jpg" width="222" height="125" alt="">
        </a>
        <strong class="title"><a href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhaw8XS8ZJuKleo90r">They Call This Guy The Vape Wizard!</a></strong>
        <div>
            <span class="views">495</span> 
            <span class="comments"><a href="http://www.example.org/videos/video.phread" data-disqus-identifier="94177"></a></span>
        </div>
    </section>
</div
```

Comment: There is only one section with the class videos in your sample so why do you expect more? I get `[{'img': 'http://hw-static.example.org/u/pic/2016/05/gbllWKHPGcQy.jpg', 'text': 'They Call This Guy The Vape Wizard!', 'link': '/videos/video.php?v=wshhaw8XS8ZJuKleo90r'}]` using the loop which is what it should return as there is only one

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Theres more than that. Thats just a snippet. I'm not going to write out all the video elements and their contents. And even if there was only one it should still show text and not be empty. The code you have in your comment is obtained without using a loop. My question is why it won't work inside the loop when the soup objects are identical.

Comment: Can you please first format your code? As a python dev you will know that code that's not properly indented is meaningless

Comment: `<p>text: {{d.text}}</p>`  Is this suppose to be a `f.text` in your loop template?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're code is having trouble here:

```
divs = soup.findAll('section', 'videos')
```

try instead:

```
divs = soup.find_all('section', 'videos')
```